# Does webstorm have some shortcut for console.log or console.info?

Tags: webstorm, shortcut

Just tired of typing `console.log` again and again, and do not find a way like `Sysout + Control + Space` in Eclipse will create `System.out.println()`.

Comment: WebStorm Guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/console-log-snippets/

Answer (score 158, accepted):

There's a predefined Postfix template that allows you to type `.log` after a JavaScript expression or string and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to transform it to `console.log(<something you've typed>)`.

You can also create a Live template (see Preferences | Editor | Live templates) that would expand into a code snippet once you type the selected abbreviation and hit Tab.

Update: there's now also a plugin that allows you to add `console.log` with a shortcut: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10986-console-log

Comment: Can also use $END$ in live template like this: `console.log($END$);` to set the cursor between the brackets in the end of autocompletion.

Comment: Remember to set up `Define` section to enable for whatever the scripting you use.

Comment: In WebStorm today from what I see the shortcut is `cl` in default not `.log

And live templates rock! love how dynamic and customizable it is

Comment: Live template for `cl` as mentioned is the way to go! Under dropdown for scope don't forget to check Expression, Statement, and Other under the "Javascript" section so that the `cl + TAB` works within an if statement too. Not sure if was anything else I'm missing but that's what I actually ended up doing.

Answer (score 115):

**Yes** it does,

`<anything>.log` and press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. This will result in `console.log(<anything>);`

ie,

`<anything>.log` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> => `console.log(<anything>);`

---

**eg1: variable**

```
let my_var = 'Hello, World!';
my_var.log + Tab => console.log(my_var);
```

**eg2: string**

```
'hello'.log + Tab => console.log('hello');
```

**eg3: string and variable**

```
'hello', my_var.log + Tab => console.log('hello', my_var);
```

Comment: I'm 2000% more efficient with this one right now ... :-D thanks!

Comment: much better than `sysout`...!

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran, brilliant! I just figured out that the all the built-in live templates are also editable. I would like to tweak this one, but I can only find the default log+tab template, and not the <anything>+tab. Do you know where it is in the editor settings, maybe?

Comment: @programstinator, The built-in`.log + <TAB>` is handled with "Postfix Code Completion", not Live Templates. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion

Answer (score 19):

**[UPDATE 2023]**

Typing `log` + Enter autocompletes to `console.log()`

Comment: @Chopper Lee this should work today without any further configuration

Comment: I am 1 million times more efficient with this right now.. together we are stronger!

Answer (score 9):

I made my own template that seems to work.
It may be useful for somebody.

Abbreviation: ll

Template text:

```
console.log('$NAME$ ', $VALUE$);
    $END$
```

Variables: **(just select the given field values by clicking drop down box)**

1. NAME - jsDefineParameter()
2. VALUE - jsSuggestVariableName

Comment: Can't get this to work. I added it to Live Templates, under Javascript. But typing ||<tab> it just tabs...no template insert. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Scott, I think you forgot to write variables. Look at this screen with my live template/shortkeys. https://yadi.sk/i/2AaC_ja33Z342U

Answer (score 6):

I'm including what I find to be the most efficient, which I added via live templates -> javascript -> applicable to "Everything". Hopefully someone finds it useful.

`console.log('L$LINE$ $MYSTRING$ ===', $MYVAR$);$END$`

What it does:
When I type `cl` and press tab, it creates the log and the first thing you type fills both `MYSTRING` and `MYVAR` variables. If you tab again, it selects `MYVAR` where you can rewrite/delete as desired. The third time you hit tab will take you to the end of the line at `$END`.
This snippet also prints the line number like `L123` but you can easily remove that if it isn't helpful because obviously most browsers show line number anyway.

You also have to set the variables' behaviour as seen in the image below:

[Edit variables setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mELPw.png)

Comment: This is really amazing and worth the 4 minutes I just spent following your directions. Thank you.

Comment: Marvellous!! I made one tiny super-simple change which allows me to have ***autocomplete*** for `$MYVAR$` (and consequently for `$MYSTRING$` at the same time). In the **`Edit variables`** dialogue, I simply replaced `$MYVAR$` with `$MYSTRING$` so that `$MYVAR$` is now on top. [Here's an image of that](https://i.ibb.co/6Dj8zYT/image.png), it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Bloke That's really amazing. Have you figured out how to prevent having to press enter 2x after selecting a var from the auto-completion menu?

Comment: @ViBoNaCci No, unfortunately not. I haven't really tried, though, I'm more or less fine with that

Answer (score 4):

use **Macros!**

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

I recorded a macro that takes the name my cursor is on and create

`console.log("#### name = ", name);`

on the next line.
and assigned a keyboard shortcut to it :)

super easy, and couldn't get Live Template to get the same result with 1 action.

to create a new macro: Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording. then record your next moves and create the desired result.
this is mine:

[image]

Comment: Hi Idan, could you share it with us please?

Comment: Hey David, i've edited the post to add some more info. i think it's better to record a macro than to edit by hand but added a screenshot of the result i got. good luck

Answer (score 4):

Try a [logit](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13432-logit) plugin. It provides the next logging pattern by default:

```
const data = 'data';    
console.log('-> data', data);
```

You can configure it.

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm using, however, One of Turbo Console Log's great powers is being able to remove all log messages at once. Haven't been able to replicate that in Webstorm.

Comment: LogIt is not usable on latest version of PHPStorm now, now sure about WebStorm

Comment: @duong-nguyen It works on the latest WebStorm (2023.2.2).

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, it somewhat mimics a turbo-console approach and gives you certain freedoms to build on it.

Step 1: Go to Editor > General > Postfix Completion;

Step 2: Click on JavaScript, click the + button, select JavaScript and TypeScript;

Step 3: In the Key input, type a alias for your command, I choose 'cl' for mine;

Step 4: In the 'Minimum language level' select your desired preference, I choose ECMAScript 6+;

Step 5: In the bellow text area, add your logic, for me it is `console.log('$EXPR$', $EXPR$, '$END$');`

Step 6: Customize however you like.

So what does all of this do?

Lets consider the following:

```
const willNeedToBeLogged = 'some value you want to check';
```

All you need to do for a console long is type

```
willNeedToBeLogged.cl + press (Tab, Enter or Spance)
```

And you will get this

```
console.log('willNeedToBeLogged', willNeedToBeLogged, '');
```

With your cursor being on the `$END$` variable, where you could write, a line, or anything you like.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom template. This can help you.

**Abbreviation:** clog

**Template code:**

```
console.log("\n\n--------------------------------");
console.log($END$);
console.log("--------------------------------\n\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest live template text:

```
console.log($END$);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a recent addition but you can write log and hit tab and console.log() will appear with the caret in between the braces.

The answer from Ekaterina Prigara (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32975087/5653914)  was very useful to me but if you want to log a string like "Test" this method is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings => Editor => Live Templates

Template text:

console.log("'zxc', '$VALUE$'", $VALUE$);

Press 'Edit Variables' button and chose for $VALUE$ as
clipboard()

In the code just copy the required variable and press 'cl' + Tab

'zxc' will allow you to filter the desired console.log in the debugger or find it in the code

Answer (score -1):

Try **Dot Log** (vscode extension), It can automatically transfer aaa.log to console.log('aaa', aaa )

Comment: VS Code extensions are not compatibles with IntelliJ IDEs.