# How to disable "[cdata]" surround for html tags in xhtml files in IntelliJ?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, jsf-2.2, emmet

When I type in xhtml files IntelliJ only autocomplete JSF options and no html option. If a write "div" and press tab, it replace by

```
<![CDATA[

    <div></div>

]]>
```

Any option enable HTML support in XHTML or disable CDATA surround?

Answer (score 1):

well if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open settings menu and search the live templates menu :

[does webstorm have some shortcut for console.log or console.info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960725/does-webstorm-have-some-shortcut-for-console-log-or-console-info)

you should be able to create your shortcuts there

here's a couple examples of variables you should be able to use there :

```
$NAME$ $VALUE$ $END$
```