# WebStorm: how to put highlighted text into console.log with prefix

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Since I use `console.log()` every day multiple times, I would like to make this a bit more efficient.

So if I have a variable:

```
const testVariable = 0;
```

and I want to log this, I usually create something like this:

```
console.log("testVariable: ", testvariable);
```

which is especially helpful (compared to just using `console.log(testVariable)` when I am logging a lot of values). So I always know which value belongs to which variable.

So my question is:

Is there an easy way in WebStorm IDE (like auto complete, code replacement, code wrapping, whatever) that I can use to highlight the variable `testVariable` and then do a shortcut or click somewhere and it creates this:

```
console.log("testVariable: ", testvariable);
```

I am very thankful for any advice.

Comment: Hello

You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66063890/4574879

Comment: You can try Webstorm's live templates. Hope this guide helps - https://youtu.be/UcWxT25DuCA

Comment: No about webstorm but you should probably use debugger more often

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcut like this, putting the value before the dot log(.log):

```
"testVariable: ", testvariable.log
```

After pressing tab, the result will be:

```
console.log("testVariable: ", testvariable)
```

As referenced here:

[JetBrains Tip Guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/console-log-snippets/)